# Проблема с mysql - не запускается

Tags: mysql, debian

Уже 2 часа пробую решить ошибку mysql

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Все, что нашел в интернете - не помогло. Система - Debian 8

Логи

```
2017-06-24T04:23:37.576309Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-06-24T04:23:37.576314Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-06-24T04:23:37.576319Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-06-24T04:23:37.576324Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'                                                     
2017-06-24T04:23:37.576387Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-06-24T04:23:37.576547Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-06-24T04:23:37.676775Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool   2017-06-24T04:23:37.676987Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170624  7:23:37
2017-06-24T04:23:39.825952Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 17836936
2017-06-24T04:23:39.827904Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-06-24T04:23:39.827919Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'                                         
2017-06-24T04:23:39.827925Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-06-24T04:23:39.827930Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-06-24T04:23:39.827934Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'                      2017-06-24T04:23:39.828062Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'                                         
2017-06-24T04:23:39.851737Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2017-06-24T04:23:45.221628Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)          2017-06-24T04:23:45.372375Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).                 2017-06-24T04:23:45.373344Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18-1) starting as process 14769 ...
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477615Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477634Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477638Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477645Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477648Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477801Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-06-24T04:23:45.477864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-06-24T04:23:45.478683Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 4G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2017-06-24T04:23:45.620033Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-06-24T04:23:45.643278Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-06-24T04:23:45.654335Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-06-24T04:24:00.181754Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-06-24T04:24:00.181820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182216Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182233Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 0, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182244Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182251Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182258Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182265Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2017-06-24T04:24:00.182271Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-06-24T04:24:00.782916Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-06-24T04:24:00.782944Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-06-24T04:24:00.782953Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-06-24T04:24:00.782961Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-06-24T04:24:00.782967Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-06-24T04:24:00.782976Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-06-24T04:24:00.783033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
```

Comment: нет, mysql не запущен. сокета нету, в конфигах путь прописан: `socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: пробовал сам создать файл сокета - не помогло

Comment: вот последних 50 строк логов (добавил в вопрос)

Comment: устранил, теперь 350 Gb свободно

Comment: еще бы знать, как действовать

Comment: ну до этого я догадался, ошибка осталась

Comment: еще при запуске появилась такая ошибка - `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory`

Comment: сделал все, что смог. теперь вываливается куча ошибок, что не правильная структура стандартных таблиц. Просит запустить `mysql_upgrade`, но я не могу войти в mysql консоль, не принимает пароль. когда пробую сбросить - не работает эта команда `usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --user=root &`

Comment: всем спасибо, смотря логи и гуглив все вышло решить. не напишу, что конкретно сделал, потому что сам не понял :)